# Hide all but one header on mobile in HTML table

Tags: css

I've built an HTML table which you can see here: [Go Free Bet](https://www.gofreebet.com/)

And the table didn't display very well at all on mobile. So, I found this CSS to make the table responsive.

However, when I add I add the CSS, while the table mostly looks great on both desktop and mobile (hallelujah!), it is showing *all* of my headers still, stacked in a black row at the top of the table.

I'm sure it's something basic I'm missing as I'm in no way experienced using code. Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Thanks very much,
HJF

```
/*Generic Styling, for Desktops/Laptops*/
table { 
  width: 100%; 
  border-collapse: collapse; 
}
/* Zebra striping */
tr:nth-of-type(odd) { 
  background: #eee; 
}
th { 
  background: #333; 
  color: white; 
  font-weight: bold; 
}
td, th { 
  padding: 6px; 
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
  text-align: left; 
}
/* 
Max width before this PARTICULAR table gets nasty
This query will take effect for any screen smaller than 760px
and also iPads specifically.
*/
@media 
only screen and (max-width: 760px),
(min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)  {

    /* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
    table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr { 
        display: block; 
    }

    /* Hide table headers (but not display: none;, for accessibility) */
    thead tr { 
        position: absolute;
        top: -9999px;
        left: -9999px;
    }

    tr { border: 1px solid #ccc; }

    td { 
        /* Behave  like a "row" */
        border: none;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #eee; 
        position: relative;
        padding-left: 50%; 
    }

    td:before { 
        /* Now like a table header */
        position: absolute;
        /* Top/left values mimic padding */
        top: 6px;
        left: 6px;
        width: 45%; 
        padding-right: 10px; 
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

    /*
    Label the data
    */
    td:nth-of-type(1):before { content: "First Name"; }
    td:nth-of-type(2):before { content: "Last Name"; }
    td:nth-of-type(3):before { content: "Job Title"; }
    td:nth-of-type(4):before { content: "Favorite Color"; }
    td:nth-of-type(5):before { content: "Wars of Trek?"; }
    td:nth-of-type(6):before { content: "Porn Name"; }
    td:nth-of-type(7):before { content: "Date of Birth"; }
    td:nth-of-type(8):before { content: "Dream Vacation City"; }
    td:nth-of-type(9):before { content: "GPA"; }
    td:nth-of-type(10):before { content: "Arbitrary Data"; }
}`/*
```

Comment: I checked on iPhone, and it looks correct to me. The black "thead" is not visible on mobile for me. What platform are you testing on?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use [w3 css style sheet](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css).. 
So play around on div class that w3 css has..

For instance if you want div to hide on small screen size you just need to add class

> w3-hide-small

In your div or your table.. 
I think

> display: block

Will not work on table element